# Selecting Checkbox when Selecting List Item in JSTree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I currently have a JSTree that shows up List Items with Checkboxes inside them.

**My goal: Send selected list items value into PHP POST Form.**

This is how I echo them on my site:

```
echo '<li id="dynamicID"><input name="checkboxname" type="checkbox" id="SameIdThanListItemID" value="checkboxvalue">List item text</li>
```

This is working fine, and my List items are showing up as intended.

We've got first the list item check, then JSTree icon, then checkbox input that I must use for a post submit (this checkbox will be hidden). The checkboxes cannot be clicked, I assume this is due to JSTree behaviour.

[image]

The tree is currently set up to disable multi selections, so we are not facing problems related with arrays. We will never work on more than a single ID.

The problem comes when I'm trying to get checkbox selected when the list items are clicked.

```
    $("#tree").bind("changed.jstree",

        function (e, data) {       

        var nodeId = $('#tree').jstree().get_selected("id")[0].id;

        // Shows up the proper ID selected, and both checkbox and 
        // list item have the same ID, so we're good untill here
        console.log(nodeId); 

        // We've got the ID properly stored into nodeId,and we've checked it with console.Log, 
        // however, the input checkbox its never getting selected.
        document.getElementById(nodeId).checked = true;

        }
    );
```

Comment: If you already have the element, then why do you get it again by ID? This seems unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, we could work straight on the ID. However, even if we are missing there; it should still be checked. It didnt fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that checkboxes wont be able to be checked/unchecked if they are inside the JSTree `<li></li>` tags.

To fix this I just made a loop outside the tree and echoed every checkbox in a hidden div. Now selecting the list items also checks the proper checkbox, so the post submit works as intended.